# Relationship between water quality at different sites and characteristics of study areas

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm investigating the relationship between the mean values of water quality parameters and the characteristics (e.g. soil types (%), landuses (%), rainfall (mm), rock types (%)) of the study area upstream of each water quality site.

As illustrated in the map below, D, F, E, G and H don't include any other site. However, there are sites that include other water quality sites (for example B includes D, F and E sites; C includes G and H sites; and A includes all other sites).

My questions is: would it be possible to use linear regression analysis to investigate the relationship between all water quality sites and the characteristics of the areas upstream of these sites taking into account that few sites include other sites (upstream)?

If not, what is the best statistical analysis that I should use to investigate this relationship?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You might want to check nested dichotomies or hierarchical models.

Comment: @Robert Exactly how would a hierarchical model be applied here? Anything of any complexity at all would have more parameters than there are monitoring stations, anyway!

Comment: @whuber If you regress against stations G and H, can't you use the estimated results as features in the C model?

Comment: @Robert By modeling how the geology (as summarized in the subwatersheds shown) affects water quality we will automatically capture the expected relationships among upstream and downstream stations. There will be *correlations* along the stream reaches due to the additive contributions along the way. One way to deal with them would be to model how the intervening geology and land cover (between, say, G/H and C) is expected to alter the water quality at the downstream end.

Comment: @whuber Right, so we could run a single model including $n$ upstream water quality features (I see up to three in the graph), or some other combined measure of upstream stations water quality.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time. Please, follow this link to find how my data look like (http://goo.gl/IZYT8W)

Comment: Would it be possible to use [Data panel] in my case?